# Confusion over the order of execution with Thread interrupt method

Tags: java, multithreading

I'm new to Java and is trying to learn the concept of thread interruption. When I run the code below, I was expecting the message "thread interrupted" to be printed before the message "called interrupt". However, it is actually the other way around. Why is this happening?

```
public class ThreadInterrupt {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
        MyThread mt1 = new MyThread();
        mt1.start();
        Thread.sleep(2000);
        mt1.interrupt();
        System.out.println("called interrupt");
    }

}

class MyThread extends Thread{

    @Override
    public void run(){
        try { 
            for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++){
                System.out.println("from secondary thread");
                sleep(1000);
            }
        } catch (InterruptedException e){
            System.out.println("thread interrupted");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Your program has a _race condition_.  Two things are going to happen after your main() thread calls `mt1.interrupt()`; the main() thread is going to print "called interrupt", and the other thread is going to print "thread interrupted".  There's no synchronization between the threads at that point.  Which ever thread gets to its `System.out.println()` call first is going to win the race and print first.  There is no way to predict which thread will win.  Maybe the main thread always wins on _your_ system, but if you run the same program on a different system, the other thread might win.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After `mt1.interrupt()` is called `main` thread continues to the next step. Thread interruption is handled (i.e: printing "thread interrupted") in `mt1` in its own line of execution. There is nothing in this code that guarantees the completion `mt1` before the `main` thread prints "called interrupt".

You may add `mt1.join()` after `mt1.interrupt()` for the `main` thread to wait for the completion of `mt1` thread.

Comment: @dzjustinli Also, it is just timing issue and if you run you program for couple of times you might even see what you were expecting.

Comment: @MadhusudanaReddySunnapu thanks for the advice. Thread is so confusion for beginners like me. Dont know whats going on lol